# error inner HTML on the wrong place

Tags: javascript

I have a form validation on 3 required input fields: name, address and city.
I made this javascript:

```
function Validate(form) {
    var error_name = "";
     var error_address = "";
      var error_city = "";
if (form.name.value.length == 0) {
            form.name.style.border = "1px solid red"; /*optioneel */
            form.name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC"; /* optioneel */

            error_name = "Name cannot be left blank!";
    }
     if (form.address.value.length == 0) {
                  form.address.style.border = "1px solid red"; /*optioneel */
                  form.address.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC"; /* optioneel */

                  error_address = "Address cannot be left blank!";
    }
      if (form.city.value.length == 0) {
                  form.city.style.border = "1px solid red"; /*optioneel */
                  form.city.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC"; /* optioneel */

                  error_city = "City cannot be left blank!";
    }
    if (error_name.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = error_name ;
            return false;
    }
     if (error_address.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = error_address ;
            return false;
    }
     if (error_city.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = error_city ;
            return false;
    }
return true;
}
document.getElementById("aanmelden").onsubmit = function () {
return Validate(this);
};
```

And this is a piece of the form:

```
<div id="form" >
<h3>Aanmelding WIES Congres</h3>
<p class="legend">Deelnemer</p>
<fieldset class="input2" id="Deelnemer">
<label>Naam:</label>
<div id="error_name"></div>
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" size="25"> 
<label class="right">Bedrijf:</label>
<input class="right" type="text" name="company" maxlength="25" size="25">   
<br/>
<label>Adres:</label>
<div id="error_address"></div>
<input type="text" name="address" maxlength="25" size="25"> <br />
<label>Postcode:</label>
<input type="text" name="postalcode" maxlength="6" size="6"> <br />
<label class="right">Plaats:</label>
<div id="error_city"></div>
<input class="right" type="text" name="city" maxlength="25" size="25">
<label>Land</label>
<select name="country">
and so on----
```

As you can see in the form, the name error should occur above the name field, the address error above the address field and so on..
But this is not happening: all errors are shown above the name field, wether it is name, address or city error...
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all of your errors are targeting the same div : `#error_name`.

Try changing each one to target the appropriate div:

```
document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = error_name;
document.getElementById("error_address").innerHTML = error_address;
document.getElementById("error_city").innerHTML = error_city;
```

Also, some of your input names do not match their references. For example:

`form.name` should be `form.form_name`
`form.address` should be `form.form_address`
`form.city` should be `form.form_city`

In order to display all the errors at once (instead of just one per form submission) you'll need to remove all the `return false;` lines and put one conditional return at the end of the function. Also, you'll need a way to "clear" the errors after the user corrects blank inputs.

Here is the restructured function:

```
function Validate(form) {

    // INITIALIZE VARIABLES

    var error_name = "";
    var error_address = "";
    var error_city = "";
    var valid = true;


    // CHECK FOR BLANK INPUTS, SET ERROR MESSAGES

    if (form.form_name.value.length == 0) {  
        error_name += "Name cannot be left blank!";
    }

    if (form.form_address.value.length == 0) {
        error_address += "Address cannot be left blank!";
    }

    if (form.form_city.value.length == 0) {
       error_city += "City cannot be left blank!";
    }


    // UPDATE ERROR MESSAGE DISPLAYS

    document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = error_name;
    document.getElementById("error_address").innerHTML = error_address;
    document.getElementById("error_city").innerHTML = error_city;


    // IF ERROR MESSAGE EXISTS, CHANGE STYLES AND SET VALID TO FALSE
    // ELSE IF NO ERRORS, RESET STYLES

    if (error_name.length > 0) {
        form.form_name.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.form_name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        form.form_name.style.border = "none";
        form.form_name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }

    if (error_address.length > 0) {
        form.form_address.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.form_address.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        form.form_address.style.border = "none";
        form.form_address.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }

    if (error_city.length > 0) {
        form.form_city.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.form_city.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        form.form_city.style.border = "none";
        form.form_city.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }


    // RETURN FORM VALIDITY (TRUE OR FALSE)
    // "FALSE" STOPS THE FORM FROM SUBMITTING

    return valid; 


}

// CONFIGURE ONSUBMIT FUNCTION

document.getElementById("aanmelden").onsubmit = function () {
  return Validate(this);
};
```

Here is a [working example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/JAC4B/2/).

Comment: oh my god, what a mistake. You are right, i forgot to change the id names. Thank you. One more question: if i want to show all the errors when required fields are empty, how do i do that?

Comment: Updated my answer. Not actually tested, so let me know what happens.

Comment: No i tried your code but it doesn't work. But depending on your code, this DOES work: instead of this line:[[code]                                 return errors_exist; // returns "true" or "false" depending on errors_exist[/code]
i made this line: return false;

Comment: But that will make the function always return false. My idea was to return false if any errors existed and to return true if no errors were found. What went wrong with my code? Did you get an error?

Comment: No , it gives no errors at all on the empty fields. At least, i see the error occur less than a second, then they dissapear... Test here on my server: http://www.jackmaessen.nl/test/form3.html

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like you missed some of the lines I added. Line 6: `var errors_exist=false;`, lines 12 16 20: `errors_exist=true;`

Comment: I changed the code now correctly but the errors appear less then a second and disappear after that: www.jackmaessen.nl/test/form3.html

Comment: Your function needed some restructuring in order to correctly detect and display all the errors. Also, I had the return value inverted. I have updated my answer.